# Can I use seq to go from 001 to 999?

Tags: bash, seq

Can I use seq to go from 001 to 999?

Comment: The answer is in [the man page](http://man.cx/seq)

Comment: How is this question - which is specifically about the command `seq` - a duplicate of a question specifically about `bash` brace expansion? The two are not the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes using the `-w` parameter:

```
-w, --equal-width
          equalize width by padding with leading zeroes
```

e.g.

```
seq -w 0 999
```

gives

```
000
001
...
999
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work in any shell on a machine that has coreutils installed:

`seq -w 1 10`  and `seq -w 1 100`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891162/bash-sequence-00-01-10